# Android volley, how to pass post parameters dynamically

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley

I'm new to google's Volley network library (and also to Android !), and I'm trying to pass POST arguments in a dynamic way !

For now I am overiding the : getParams() method : 
And returning the params in an hard coded manner.

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams()
{
       Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       params.put("login", "my_login");
       params.put("password", "my_password");
       return params;
}
```

**I would like to pass variables instead of "hard coded" strings...**

First I tried to put my Map of params as a member of my class, but class members are not avaible in the getParams() method.

Maybe I could use a singleton class to wich I could give the parameters I want to pass and get them back using its instance in the getParams() method ? But I don't think that it would be the right manner.

Below is the hole code of my Volley's request :

```
RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

String url = "https://theUrlToRequest";

StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            JSONObject mainObject = null;
                            try {
                                Log.i("app", "Result = " + response);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.i("app", "Fail on Login" + error.toString());
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("login", "my_login");
                    params.put("password", "my_password");

                    return params;
                }
            };

queue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: Why don't you just create some variables and equalize them to class variables before request and add variables that you created to params?

Comment: its necessary to return `Map<String, String>` from `getParams()`, not to define it there only. You can create your own collection as class level variable and return it from `getParams()`.

Comment: @shank : This is a good idear. I'll try this immediatly. Thanks.

Comment: You should extends StringRequest  and add a attr to store params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case , you can create a Class extends StringRequest. Add an attr to store params and return it in getParams();

```
MyStringRequest extends StringRequest{

    private Map params = new HashMap();
    public MyStringRequest (Map params,int mehotd,String url,Listener listenr,ErrorListener errorListenr){
    super(mehotd,url,listenr,errorListenr)

        this.params = params

    }
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){

        return params;

    }

}

RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();

String url = "https://theUrlToRequest";
Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("login", "my_login");
params.put("password", "my_password");
MyStringRequest postRequest = new MyStringRequest (params ,Request.Method.POST, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>(){
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener(){
    }
);
queue.add(postRequest);
```