# How to pass Object and String as parameters in Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I can't seem to figure out how to pass both a string and an object as parameters in Volley. All of my calls currently use strings only but for this special case I have to pass a mixture of object and string to the API.

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            JSONObject content = new JSONObject();

            try {
                content.put("original_msg","hello");
                content.put("new_msg","hi");

                params.put("session_id", sessionId);
                params.put("type", "reply");
                params.put("content", content); //the object
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return params; //returning an error: Incompatible Types
        }
```

Comment: you can try this if it helps: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746619/android-volley-how-to-pass-post-parameters-dynamically?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is also considered a string and all object provide a `toString()` method so that any subclass can create a string representation of that Object.

```
params.put("content", content.toString());
```

Appart from that you need to change it to `Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();`

Comment: Oh my gosh! It worked! :) Thank you very much! Hmmm... seems hacky though 'cause in database it is saved as string when it should be an object.... hmmmm...

Comment: Hmmm... seems hacky though 'cause in database it is saved as string when it should be an object.... hmmmm...

Comment: Sorry I don't get the part of being *hacky* approach. It is the framework design so as an API consumer we need to satisfy the conditions. To be honest your *content data* should be a Body request and not part of the header or use the `JsonObjectRequest` but it would be another discussion so I limit my answer to the question scope.

Comment: okies thanks. What I did is to just JSON.parse the content on the server so it'll be saved as a real object not an object string on the database. Hmmm I'm using multipartrequest for this since it's a form data that can contain audio, video, etc. Thanks a lot for your response. It's the one I use. :)

Answer (score -1):

Change `protected Map<String, String>`    to `protected Map<String, Object>`

Comment: Hello, I did that also but having `getParams() in Anonymous class.... clashes with getParams() in com.android.volley.Request"; attempting to use incompatible return types`.

Comment: And what object is calling getParams()?

Comment: This is incorrect Volley takes a Map<String,String>